# Как на этапе компиляции сгенерировать последовательные числа, т.е `0,1,2...` чтобы потом их поместить в шаблон

Tags: c++, метапрограммирование

Как на этапе компиляции сгенерировать последовательные числа, т.е `0,1,2...` в данном примере

```
template<typename T, int size, int random>
auto statik()
{
    static T t[size];
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cin >> statik<int, 10, /*каждий раз генерируеться новое число*/>()[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно, привлечь систему сборки, если это cmake/qmake/.., и хранить счетчик в отдельном файле. Или, если нужны именно случайные числа, использовать \_\_TIME\_\_ + Compile time string hashing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111667/compile-time-string-hashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разве что ради спортивного интереса:

```
template<size_t n>
struct Elem{
    enum { res = 1 + Elem<n - 1>::res };
};

template<>
struct Elem<0> {
    enum { res = 0 };
};
template <size_t n, size_t...args>
struct A {
    static constexpr auto& array =
        A<n - 1, Elem<n>::res, args...>::array;
};
template <size_t...args>
struct A<0, args...> {
    static constexpr int array[] = { 0, args... };
};

template <size_t n>
static constexpr auto& Array = A<n>::array;

//пример использования
int main()
{   
    constexpr unsigned N = 8;
    for (unsigned n : Array<N>)
        cout << n << ' ';
    //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
}
```

Вполне можно  значение первого члена передать тоже в шаблон и создать диапазон начиная от любого числа